# How to specify browser language in Puppeteer from predefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, javascript-objects

I need to set navigator.languages from predefined variable.
something like this:

```
let predefinedLanguage=["bn-BD","bn"]
            await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
                Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
                    get: function() {
                        return predefinedLanguage;
                    }
                });
            });
```

But with code like this i always end upt getting this for navigator.languages

```
{
     "languages": {
          "error": true,
          "message": "ReferenceError: predefinedLanguage is not defined"
     }
}
```

I understand that i cant access predefinedLanguage variable inside page.evaluateOnNewDocument but I simply cant find the solution. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args), you just need to use argument to transfer the variable value:

```js
let predefinedLanguage=["bn-BD","bn"];
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument((language) => {
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
    get: function() {
      return language;
    }
  });
}, predefinedLanguage);
```